# Airflow with http parsing

Tags: airflow, etl

I'm taking first steps in Airflow and have questions with a true DAG composition. Preliminarily read the documentation on the main points.

1. Common project description (for now):
   1.1. start of the project
   1.2. one scheduler instance
   1.3. executor = LocalExecutor (temporary requirement)
   1.4. parsing http reources
   1.5. low load by tasks and data
2. Logic steps:
   2.1. Load data by http,
   2.2. Parsing and formating,
   2.3. Data addition with a remote request by items
   2.4. Store data to a file (temporary requirement, in the future - DB)
3. Solution (after the documentation reading):
   3.1. SimpleHttpOperator:

- load data
- parsing and formating (response_filter)
  3.2. @task (PythonOperator)
  3.2.1. Use xComs:
- get the data from 3.1
- the data addition
  3.3. @task
  3.3.1. Use xComs:
- get the data from 3.2
- store to local file

4. Comments:
   4.1. Use such composition to separate logic steps for future possible problems localization.
5. Questions:
   5.1.The composition seems wrong?
   5.1.1. Common time delays
   5.1.2. data exchange by xComs: future high load problems
   5.2. SimpleHttpOperator using it is a common practice?
   Possible cases when need the load data group from one resource with pages iteration - use custom @task?
6. Possible corrections (how I see it)
   6.1. Сombine tasks into one:

- all to one with 5.2. implementation
- 3.2. and 3.3.

Direct me to tru solution.